Составное прозвище
Как следует писать составное прозвище, одна часть которого — кличка, а другая — уточнение, более точная характеристика, например: "Тулло (,) белый мишка"?

• Я думаю, что правильно надо написать так (все слова с заглавной; без дефиса, без запятой, без кавычек): Тулло Белый Мишка.
• Из правил Розенталя (Собственные имена лиц и клички животных):

1. Имена, отчества, фамилии, прозвища, псевдонимы пишутся с прописной буквы:
Александр Сергеевич Пушкин, Гай Юлий Цезарь, Эмиль Золя, Пётр Первый (Пётр I), Всеволод Большое Гнездо, Екатерина Великая, Тимур Железная Пята, Федька Умойся Грязью, Синдбад Мореход, Демьян Бедный, Лже-Нерон, Рыцарь Печального Образа (о Дон-Кихоте) и т. д.
Примечание. Прозвище никогда в кавычки не заключается: Владимир Красное Солнышко, Ричард Львиное Сердце, Ванька Каин, Служанка по прозвищу Великий Могол.

• Примеры:
Пеппи Длинный Чулок (если слитно, то Пеппи Длинныйчулок);
Ниалл Девять Заложников, Генрих Кривая Шея, Эдуард Черный Принц;
Белый Бим Черное Ухо.
